# STM32F0 I2C not working

Tags: c, i2c, stm32, stm32f0, st

I am trying to establish I2C communication between [STM32F030K6T6](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00088500.pdf) mikrokontroller and [HH10D](http://www.hoperf.com/upload/sensor/hh10d.pdf) humidity sensor. The problem is, that after I call I2C_TransferHandling() the I2C_ISR_TXIS flag won't be set, and the program stucks in the loop waiting for it.

Here is my code, I made it based on the example code in the std periph library.

```
void initI2C()
{
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_1);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_1);

    GPIO_InitTypeDef  GPIO_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_OD;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    I2C_InitTypeDef  I2C_InitStructure;
    I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Ack = I2C_Ack_Enable;
    I2C_InitStructure.I2C_AcknowledgedAddress = I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit;
    I2C_InitStructure.I2C_AnalogFilter = I2C_AnalogFilter_Enable;
    I2C_InitStructure.I2C_DigitalFilter = 0x00;
    I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Mode = I2C_Mode_I2C;
    I2C_InitStructure.I2C_OwnAddress1 = 0x00; 
    I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Timing = 0x00201D2B;

    I2C_Init(I2C1, &I2C_InitStructure);

    I2C_Cmd(I2C1, ENABLE);
}

uint8_t I2C_Read(uint8_t address, uint8_t reg){

    uint8_t ReadByte;

    I2C_TransferHandling(I2C1,address, 1, I2C_SoftEnd_Mode, I2C_Generate_Start_Write);
    while(I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C1, I2C_ISR_TXIS) == RESET); //the program stucks here

    I2C_SendData(I2C1, (uint8_t)reg);
    while(I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C1, I2C_ISR_TC) == RESET);

    I2C_TransferHandling(I2C1,address, 1, I2C_AutoEnd_Mode,I2C_Generate_Start_Read);

    ReadByte = I2C_ReceiveData(I2C1);
    while(I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C1, I2C_ISR_RXNE) == RESET);

    while(I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C1, I2C_FLAG_STOPF));
    I2C_ClearFlag(I2C2, I2C_ICR_STOPCF);

    return ReadByte;
}
```

And the calling of the read function:

```
    uint16_t readSensitivity()
    {
//The sensor address is 0x01, the register adresses are 0x0A and 0x0B
        return (I2C_Read(0x01, 0x0A) << 8) + I2C_Read(0x01, 0x0B);
    }
```

The relevant part of my schematic is following:
[image]
[image]

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The I²C Address of a `24C02` EEPROM cannot be `0x01`. The HH10D datasheet is misleading in this, the real I²C address should be something like `A2`, see [M24C02](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00071904.pdf).

Comment: You are right, the HH10D was misleading.